# need help to write this code to parallel arrays in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, parallel-arrays

if anyone can please help to convert this if else statements in to parallel array to find out calculate the discounts.

> [**Parallel Arrays**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)
>
> *is a data structure for representing arrays of records. It keeps a separate, homogeneous array for each field of the record, each having the same number of elements. Then, objects located at the same index in each array are implicitly the fields of a single record. Pointers from one object to another are replaced by array indices. This contrasts with the normal approach of storing all fields of each record together in memory.
>
>   For example, one might declare an array of 100 names, each a string, and 100 ages, each an integer, associating each name with the age that has the same index.*

'discount calculations of total cost with GST

```
if TotGST >= 5000 AND TotGST <= 9999 then 
discount = (TotGST * 0.05)
else 
    if TotGST >= 10000 AND TotGST <= 49999 then
    discount = (TotGST * 0.08)
    else 
        if TotGST >= 50000 then 
        else        
        discount = (TotGST * 0.1)
        end if 
    end if 
end if
```

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by parallel array?

Comment: @BrianWhite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array

Comment: Thanks a lot  its really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, set up the parallel arrays.
Then loop through the arrays in a loop to find the matching range.
If it matches, apply the discount.

See sample code below

```vbs
<%       
Function CalcDiscount(nAmount)
    ' Set up the arrays
    Amin = Array(5000,10000,50000)
    Amax = Array(9999,49999,-1)
    Adiscount = Array(0.05,0.08,0.10)

    ' Initialise other variables
    nUpper = uBound(Adiscount) 
    i = 0
    bDiscount = false
    CalcDiscount = 0

    ' Loop through the array to find a matching amount range
    do until (i > nUpper or bDiscount = true) 
        If (nAmount >= Amin(i) and (nAmount <= Amax(i) or Amax(i) = -1)) Then
            ' Apply discount
            CalcDiscount = nAmount * Adiscount(i)
            bDiscount = true
        End If
        i = i + 1
    loop

End Function 

' Run some test cases
TotGST = 1000
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")


TotGST = 5000
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")


TotGST = 5500
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")

TotGST = 9999
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")


TotGST = 10000
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")

TotGST = 50000
nDiscount=CalcDiscount(TotGST)
response.write("TotGST=" & TotGST & " Discount = " & nDiscount & "<BR>")

%>
```

Output

```
TotGST=1000 Discount = 0
TotGST=5000 Discount = 250
TotGST=5500 Discount = 275
TotGST=9999 Discount = 499.95
TotGST=10000 Discount = 800
TotGST=50000 Discount = 5000
```